# Type mismatch in Spark UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have created following UDF to fetch only 1st part of decimal values.

```scala
def udf_cleansing(col1 : Double) = udf((col1 : Double) => {
val col2 : String = f"$col1%.5f"
if(col2.trim == "" || col2 == null ) 0.toString else col2.substring(0,col2.indexOf("."))}
)
```

However, while calling this function using command like

```scala
df_aud.select(udf_cleansing(df_aud("HASH_TTL")))
```

I am getting follwing error :-

> <console>:42: error: type mismatch;
>
> found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
>
> required: Double
>
> df_aud.select(udf_cleansing(df_aud("HASH_TTL")))

I tried with command

```scala
df_aud.withColumn("newc",udf_cleansing(df_aud("HASH_TTL").cast("double")))
```

Still getting same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that Scala treats `df_aud("HASH_TTL")` as a parameter to `udf_cleansing` function, not to UDF this function returned.

Instead, you should write:

```
def udf_cleansing = udf(
    (col1 : Double) => {
        val col2 : String = f"$col1%.5f"
        if(col2.trim == "" || col2 == null ) 0.toString else col2.substring(0,col2.indexOf("."))
    }
)
```

Now `udf_cleansing` returns an UDF. UDF1 function as a parameter of type Column and this column's value is provided to wrapped inner function.

And then use is exactly how you tried to use this function.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [spark functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) as much as possible. If any of the *inbuilt functions* cannot satisfy your needs, then only I would suggest you to go with `udf` functions as `udf` functions would require the data to be *serialized* and *deserialized* to perform the operation you have devised.

Your `udf` function can be performed by using `format_string` and `substring_index` *inbuilt functions* as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df_aud.select(substring_index(format_string("%.5f", df_aud("HASH_TTL")), ".", 1))
```