# Write a Spark UDF which will return a String value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro

I have been playing around with Apache Spark scala to see how I can deserialize avro record based on the avro record dynamically. Instead of passing avro schema directly to from_avro function, I wrote a udf which will return a schema based on the schema id by checking schema registry. The udf is given below.

```
    val extractSchemaById = udf((message: Array[Byte]) => {
      val schemaId = ByteBuffer.wrap(message.slice(1, 5)).getInt()
      val schemaString: String = schemaRegistryClient.getSchemaById(schemaId).rawSchema().toString

      schemaString
    })
```

I tried calling the from_avro function as below.

```
      .select(from_avro($"value", extractSchemaById($"value")).alias("data")).alias("data")
```

Iam getting the following exception.

```
type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: String
      .select(from_avro($"value", extractSchemaById($"value")).alias("data")).alias("data")
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625608/type-mismatch-in-spark-udf) looks similar

Comment: @o_O I had already tried it. But it didn't work